# Bi-quadratic interpulation in scikit image formula?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to understand the interpolation formula of a given image in scikit image when the input for the "order" parameter is "Bi-quadratic".
Unfortunately, no documentation  exists, and I can't find information on the web also.
[Link to the order explanation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale)

Comment: http://www.geocomputation.org/1999/082/gc_082.htm
Check section 3.5. Does it help?
It's quite a classic method which may explain why it is not precised in the documentation. I guess you could open an issue in the scikit-image github repo for enhancing the documentation of this function.